# m operator of Regular Expression in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the difference between m[] and m{} regular expression in Perl? How does $1, $2, etc matches the pattern "(((Cu)(Na))(Hg))"?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between `m{}` and `m[]`. Perl lets you change the delimiters of regexes to make them easier to read in a given context.

`$var =~ m/*.zip/` and `$var =~ m{*.zip}` and `$var =~ m[*.zip]` and `$var =~ m#*.zip#` all match the same way.

For capture groups, captures are always handled from left to right, so for your example:

```
my $foo = 'CuNaHg';
if ( $foo =~ m{(((Cu)(Na))(Hg))} ) {
    print $1; # CuNaHg 
    print $2; # CuNa
    print $3; # Cu
    print $4; # Na
    print $5; # Hg
}
```

Comment: Specifically, left to right order of the opening parentheses. [Details here](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Capture-groups), and [this section of perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc) describes the few match delimiters that have special meaning (`{}` and `[]` do not).

Comment: @Grinnz, There is technically two special things about `()`, `[]` and `{}`: 1) The opening delimiter doesn't terminate the pattern, and 2) They are nestable (e.g `m[a[bc]d]`)

Comment: @ikegami That is true, and also applies to `<>`, but I meant special meaning to the matching operation it's applied to, such as if you use single-quotes as the delimiter. [The previous perlop section](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) also goes into more detail on quoting delimiters.